# create drop down menu on click of an image in primefaces?

Tags: javascript, primefaces

Create drop down menu on click of an image in primefaces like facebook or gmail

```
    <p:menuitem styleClass="label" value="logout" ">
      <p:graphicImage library="images" name="user-small-icon.png" "/>
      <h:outputText value="welcome #{coreg.regapp.sessionName}"   />
    </p:menuitem>


     welcome rahmath
```

Next to that image is there I need dropdown and in that drop down I need logout option

Comment: Please explain more, ,menu where ? for what ? in facebook or gmail they "usually" don't have only one menu in the site ! maybe a screenshot

Comment: i need a pop up on clicking the image on right side of my application for logout purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a contextMenu for the image and populte the required menu items into the context menu. Check out the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/contextMenuAttach.jsf) of context menu on the primefaces website for more information on how to implement it.

EDIT:

The below code works for showing a context menu on left-click on an image on my page.

```
<h:graphicImage library="img" name="myimage.png" id="imageMy" ></h:graphicImage>
<p:contextMenu for="imageMy" id="context" event="click">                   
     <p:menuitem value="Save" 
                            icon="ui-icon-disk"/>  
     <p:menuitem value="Update" 
                            icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"/>  
     <p:menuitem value="Delete" icon="ui-icon-close"  
                            ajax="false"/>  
     <p:menuitem value="Homepage" url="http://www.primefaces.org"  
                            icon="ui-icon-extlink"/>  
 </p:contextMenu>
```

Comment: :i need dropdown for logout purpose for example just see above stackexchange and a downward arrow i want to perform same operation for logout purpose its like getting a popup box

Comment: context menu will give you a dropdown kind of a menu when you click on the image. It will be like the menu you get when you right click(in Windows).

Comment: adarsh:i want on left click of button just as like want to logout from stackoverflow website same thing i want can u show it with example

Comment: :or i would like dropdown on onmouseover or onmousedown i want dropdown menu for logout

Comment: You can do that using the context menu. Should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: adarsh:bro i want on left click not right click contextmenu supports only right click

Comment: What version of primefaces are you using ?

Comment: I have edited the answer to add a working example. I am using primefaces 3.5

Comment: primefaces 4.0 version

Comment: :thanks a lot i have one more problem can u please have a look into this http://stackoverflow3227175.com/q/21878146/